# CSS Backround Autosizing Issues

Tags: html, css

I am very new to web development and am in need of some help. I have built a login page using JavaScript, html, and CSS. I want my background to autosize to fit the screen of whatever device is accessing the page. I've researched how to do this and have implemented it through this CSS styling:

```
    body, html {
      background: url("/images/Test.jpg"), #2d2d2d;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

[image]

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Just a small correction following my edit: considering that you're new to web development, Node.js and JavaScript are not the same. JavaScript is the language being used to make web pages interactive, while Node.js is a server-side platform that utilizes JavaScript to write web applications. If you're writing JavaScript in a web browser - it's just JavaScript, and has nothing to do with Node.js. :)

Comment: Hi @TalKoren, thank you for the clarification. I've used node.js for the login verification, read/write to my database that contains the application info, and am going to be using node.js to implement most of the major functionalities of the app. I just thought I'd include Node.js in the title because I didn't know if that would affect the answer.

Comment: awesome - it was a bit unclear, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-size: 100%; //to fill screen
background-position:center; //to center on screen
```

background cover will shrink image.

Comment: Hi @osmanraifgunes, when I use your code above, I am still having sizing issues. The bottom of the picture is chopped off in my background. Any idea why or how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: In different screen ratios you have to sacrifice from an edge, bottom or right.

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: cover;` might be your hero in css ;)